# Re arrange the Billing and shipping address in onepage checkout

Tags: magento

I want to display the shipping address as first section and billing address as second section in onepage checkout of magento.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you have done ?

Comment: This will be harder than you think to make it work well. I suggest not going down that road, or look for a reputable third-party checkout extension instead.